# web interstitial ad not loading every time

Tags: web, ads, interstitial, google-publisher-tag

I am following Google Docs for displaying web interstitial ads. [tutorial link](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/samples/display-web-interstitial-ad). Whenever I check with my own ads it does not load the ads after a few refreshes of the web page.  But if I delete cookies then it displays and stops displaying after a few refreshes. I am not able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/samples/display-web-interstitial-ad) you mentionned :

> Web interstitials have a fixed frequency cap. This prevents the same
> user from being shown an interstitial more than once per hour, per
> subdomain.

A 1/hour capping is applied globally, that's why deleting your cookies makes you see your ad again.